# I'm using MultipartEntity to post form data into server and it's worked in java6 but it doesn't worked in java7.Is there any other way to do it?

Tags: java-7

```
FileBody uploadFilePart = new FileBody(new File("/home/User/Downloads/reports.csv"));
MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity();
reqEntity.addPart("Attachment_field", uploadFilePart); 
reqEntity.addPart("username",new StringBody("test"));
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://test.com");
post.setEntity(reqEntity);
HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
```

/*Note:
The FileBody comes correctly in java7 but StringBody parameters(username,..) comes as 0bytes.
*/

Answer (score 0):

Dont know issue in yours. Post the error. However you can check this, this is working for me in Java 7 as well as java6

```java
String fileName="";//file name to be uploaded
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
FileBody fileContent= new FiSystem.out.println("hello");
StringBody comment = new StringBody("Filename: " + fileName);
MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity();
reqEntity.addPart("file", fileContent);
httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);

HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
```

Hope this helps with your problem

Comment: In server side I'm using ServletFileUpload class to parse the request and gets the multipart content. I can able to get the file part(size=285bytes) but i can't able to get the form parametes(ex:username size=0bytes). It happens in java7 only.